# Unexpected exception expected <nameoftheclass> but was <java.lang.AssertionError>

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, netbeans, assertion

i don´t know how to pass this test. I tried every solution i thought of and didnt find a solution on the internet neither. Its my exam to school.
So, I have this class MojeException.java:

```
public class MojeException extends RuntimeException {

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of <code>NewException</code> without detail
     * message.
     */
    public MojeException() throws AssertionError{
       
    }

    /**
     * Constructs an instance of <code>NewException</code> with the specified
     * detail message.
     *
     * @param msg the detail message.
     */
    public MojeException(String msg) throws AssertionError {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

And i have this test:

```
 @Test(expected = MojeException.class)
    public void testKonstruktor11() {
        Rozmer rozmer = new Rozmer(0, 0, 0);
        fail() ;       
    }
```

The error i got is "Unexpected exception, expected but was<java.lang.AssertionError>"

The main class is this, however i dont know if its not irelevant:

```
public class Rozmer {
public static final double DIMENZE_MAX = 100;
public static final double DIMENZE_MIN = .1;
private static final double TO_CM = 100.00;
private final long delka;
private final long sirka;
private final long vyska;
 public Rozmer(double delka, double sirka, double vyska){
        this.delka = (long)(delka * TO_CM);
        this.sirka = (long) (sirka * TO_CM);
        this.vyska = (long) (vyska * TO_CM);
    }
public double getDelka() {
        return delka/TO_CM;
    }

    public double getSirka() {
        return sirka/TO_CM;
    } 
    
    public double getVyska() {    
        return vyska/TO_CM;
    }
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Rozmer{" + "delka= " + delka/TO_CM + "0,sirka= " + sirka/TO_CM + "0,vyska= " + vyska/TO_CM + "0}";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 89 * hash + (int) (this.delka ^ (this.delka >>> 32));
        hash = 89 * hash + (int) (this.sirka ^ (this.sirka >>> 32));
        hash = 89 * hash + (int) (this.vyska ^ (this.vyska >>> 32));
        return hash;
    }
@Override    
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Rozmer other = (Rozmer) obj;
        if (this.delka != other.delka) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.sirka != other.sirka) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.vyska != other.vyska) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
public static boolean kontrolaDimenze(double dimenze) {
        return DIMENZE_MIN <= dimenze && dimenze<=DIMENZE_MAX;
    }
```

Thanks for all your ideas and solutions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you are instructing JUnit that in your test you expect that a `MojeException` (which is a `RuntimeException`) will be eventually thrown, and that it's not done by fail(), which instead throws an `AssertionException`, so a total different one.
So, you have to throw that specific exception somewhere, otherwise your test will always fail.
The best point to do that is possibly in your constructor, because it's the only method you invoked in the test, so it looks like you are testing that specific constructor. Maybe after checking one of the input parameters, which doesn't match an expected value, you can throw your exception.
Here is just an example of how you can modify your `Rozmer` class constructor:

```
public Rozmer(double delka, double sirka, double vyska) throws MojeException {
    if(delka == 0.0 || sirka == 0.0 || vyska == 0.0) {
        throw new MojeException("Unsupported value for delka, sirka or vyska");
    }
    this.delka = (long)(delka * TO_CM);
    this.sirka = (long) (sirka * TO_CM);
    this.vyska = (long) (vyska * TO_CM);
}
```

Then remove the `fail()` from your test.